# FFT Basic Question

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I've followed a basic tutorial on FFTs and trying to get my head around what's going on here. As I understand it fourier transform converts from time domain to frequency domain. So in a hypothetical waveform the FT will show the relative presence of each frequency in the waveform. That is my understanding but clearly I am missing something very simple because I can't get my head around this simple example..

The 2 charts below show the waveform (right) and FT representation (left) [(source: 1)](https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter24.04-FFT-in-Python.html).

As I can see it the waveform (right) has a high occurence of the amplitude at 2 so I would expect a peak at 2 Hz on the FT (left). But instead the peak is at 1.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

[image: FFT Python]

Comment: The function is periodic with period at or near 1 second.  That is why there is a huge peak at freq=1.  The amplitude is a different story.  If your red curve were multiplied by 10, the frequencies where there are spikes would stay the same and would *not* be multiplied by 10.

Comment: Somebody else had a nice comment but deleted it.  I think the point was that in the tutorial, there are three frequencies present:  $f \in \{1,4,7\}$ and the red curve is the sum of sinusoids at these three fundamental frequencies.  That is why there are spikes at $\{1,4,7\}$ in the blue plot.

Comment: Amplitude is irrelevant - it maps to frequency. I don't really understand your confusion. Why would an amplitude of $2$ mean anything?